# How do you equip legendary potions?

Tags: diablo-iii

I just received a [Bottomless Potion of Regeneration](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bottomless-potion-of-regeneration) and it seems there are 5 other legendary potions as well [(See here)](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/potion/)

But, it doesn't mention how to equip the potion. How do I equip the potion?

Comment: Congrats!  Where did you find it?  I've been hunting one for a while now.

Comment: @Mkalafut I found mine in a Torment III rift. They only drop in Rifts, but it might have to be Torment I or above.

Comment: Good to know.  I often do Torment I or II so I'll start doing more rifts.  Thanks!

Comment: @Bob2Chiv That is not correct. They can drop everywhere if you play on t1 or higher and you are at least lvl 61+. (see http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/12248895035#7)

Comment: @Mordrag Hmm, not sure where I heard that then. Thanks for setting me straight.

Comment: I found 1 in act1, campaign mode on torment 1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just like you equip a normal potion: Drag it into the potion-slot of your actionbar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: I didn't know how to equip normal potions either. Seems like I tried everything but this (retrospectively) obvious answer; thanks!

Comment: >Just like how you *used* to equip potions. You don't have different potions to equip anymore besides legendary ones.